# Getting unknown type name My structure c++

Tags: c++

After doing some research into solving the getting unknown type (insert my class), I have been unable to find out why my compiler shows this.

I have 2 files stack.h and stack.cpp

This is stack.h

```
#ifndef stack_h
#define stack_h

const int max_stack = 50; 

class IStack {

    friend class StackSeq;

    public: 

    IStack()
    :_top(0)
    {}; 

    void Push(int i); 
    int Pop(); 

    private: 

    int _arr[max_stack]; 
    int _top; 


};  

class StackSeq
{
    public: 

    StackSeq(IStack const & stack); 
    bool AtEnd() const; 
    void Advance(); 
    int GetNum() const; 

    private: 

    IStack const & _stack; 
    int _iCur; 

}; 

#endif // stack_h
```

And this is stack.cpp which defines the function in stack.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include "stack.h"


StackSeq::StackSeq(IStack const & stack)
: _stack(stack), _iCur(0)
{}

bool StackSeq::AtEnd() const
{
    return (_iCur == _stack._top)
}

void StackSeq::Advance()
{
    assert (!AtEnd()); 
    _iCur++; 
}

int StackSeq::GetNum()
{
     return _stack._arr[_iCur]; 
}

void IStack::Push(int i)
{
    assert (_top < max_stack); 
    _arr[_top] = i; 
    _top++; 

}

int IStack::Pop()
{
    assert (_top > 0); 
    _top--; 
    return _arr[_top]; 

}
```

**If I am clearly defining IStack in my .cpp file why is the compiler telling me error: unknown type name 'IStack'. How do I solve this?**

Thanks in advance,
Sarthak

Comment: Which line of code is the error message being reported on exactly? Have you tried renaming your files? I'm guessing your compiler already has a `stack.h` header for some other purpose. That is a pretty generic name.

Comment: That's not one of the errors I get: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/14d28d282a256325. Make sure the code you pasted is what's actually being compiled, and that the `#include "stack.h"` got the file you expected.

Comment: `StackSeq::AtEnd` is missing a semicolon on the return line.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] and the full compiler output